# Grunt reloading JSON from file and updating task options

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I am using a configuration file with JSON format containing names of other files which I concatenate when one of the files is changed. It works great so far, but I want to make the Grunt to reload the configuration file once it's changed (I remove or add something to the JSON) and update other task options (the concat task).

Here is my simplified Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    function getModules() {
        var modules = grunt.file.readJSON('src/js/modules.json').modules;
        for ( var module in modules ) {
            if ( modules.hasOwnProperty(module) ) {
                modules[module] = 'src/js/modules/' + modules[module] + '.js';
            }
        }
        modules.push('src/js/scripts.js');
        return modules;
    }
    var modules = getModules();

    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';',
            },
            dist: {
                src: modules,
                dest: 'assets/js/scripts.min.js',
            },
        },

        watch: {
            js_modules: {
                files: ['src/js/modules.json'],
                tasks: ['reload_modules', 'concat'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    livereload: true,
                },
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('reload_modules', "Reload JavaScript modules", function() {
        modules = getModules();
    });
};
```

As you can see I have some attempt to solve my problem, but the updated `modules` variable is not used in the `concat` task. The task uses the variable value loaded when the grunt default task is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to overwrite the config using `grunt.config.merge`:

```
var config = {
    // ...
};

grunt.config.init(config);

grunt.registerTask('reload_modules', "Reload JavaScript modules", function() {
    config.concat.options.dist.src = getModules();
    grunt.config.merge(config);
});
```

http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config

Comment: Simple and easy. Thank you!